# Unable to set the right d3.extent accessor

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having problems setting my Y scale dynamically in this example. Would love if someone could help!
I am able to get the X axis setup perfectly, but I can't find how to refer to my Y data to define the extent of my axis. Right now I get the scale to go from -2 to 500, the part of the code that's not working is the commented out line.
Thanks for your time!

Plunk here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/eQ4HgxQC49CZIPVBXjQX

```
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d["year"] = parseDate(d["year"])
  });

  var subset = data.filter(function(el) {
    return el.metric === "rank"
  });


  var concentrations = productCategories.map(function(category) {
      return {
        category: category,
        datapoints: subset.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d["year"],
            concentration: +d[category]
          }
        })
      }
    })

  xScale.domain(d3.extent(subset, function(d) {
    return d["year"];
  }));

  yScale.domain([-2, 500]);
  //yScale.domain(d3.extent(subset, function(d) {return d["rank"] })); //
```

Comment: Try a coercion: put + before d["rank"]: `+d["rank"]`

Comment: @Capivara There's no `rank` key in your data, so D3 can't calculate a min and max on it.

Comment: Thanks @Gerardo, coercion didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a `rank` in your data, as nikoshr asked?

Comment: @nikoshr, I see what you mean about no column called "rank" existing, but if i am able to pull the data to draw the line, this data must live somewhere, so I am wondering how I can access it...

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado, in the plunk, the data is shown: https://plnkr.co/edit/eQ4HgxQC49CZIPVBXjQX

Comment: Now I see it. But your line is based on date (that is, d["year"]) and concentration (that is, d["category"]). So, you have to use d["category"] in your d3.extent.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado yes, I tried that also with no success

Comment: But it's not "rank". The way you created your CSV, rank is just a value for "metric". If you console.log your data, you'll see a bunch of objects, and in each one the pair `{metric:"rank"}`.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado and agreed on your comment on how data was organized . So I have no way of accessing this rank data to define a better axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll provide a **temporary** solution, because I'm sure there must be a shorter and cleaver way to do it.

First, let's extract all values that are not "year" from your data:

```
var values = productCategories.map(function(category){
    return subset.map(function(d){
        return  +d[category]
    })
});
```

Then, let's merge this array of arrays:

```
var merged = [].concat.apply([], values);
```

And, finally:

```
yScale.domain(d3.extent(merged));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, i was finally able to solve that in a clean way:

```
yScale.domain([
d3.min(concentrations, function(c) { return d3.min(c.datapoints,function(v) { return v.concentration; }); }),
d3.max(concentrations, function(c) { return d3.max(c.datapoints, function(v) { return v.concentration; }); })
]);
```

But now I have another problem, since I want the Y scale to display the extremes of only one selected array. That means I have to filter while I parse the data. Not really sure how to do it, will probably open another question. Thank you so much @gerardofurtado for your time and patience!